# Python, CSV: count number of male employees for each 30 min segment

Tags: python, csv, datetime

**What is given:**

- Office consists of 3 types of buildings: building A, B, C.
- Employees work in 3 departments: IT, Marketing, Management
- There is a pass system that records time, department, building_type, gender(m/f)

**The goal** is to count number of *male* employees for each department-building_type pair for each 30 minute segment.

Here's a piece of **CSV** data to process:

```
time,department,building_type,gender
2017-09-07 14:46:14,018,management,b,m
2017-09-07 14:49:14,081,it,a,m
2017-09-07 14:55:14,127,management,c,f
2017-09-07 15:40:16,318,marketing,c,m
2017-09-07 16:01:14,018,it,a,m
2017-09-07 16:10:14,081,it,a,m
2017-09-07 17:46:14,127,marketing,c,m
2017-09-07 17:49:16,318,management,c,m
2017-09-07 18:00:14,018,it,c,f
2017-09-07 18:02:14,081,management,a,m
2017-09-07 18:33:14,127,marketing,b,m
2017-09-07 18:56:16,318,marketing,a,m
```

- The main time period to process is 2017-09-07 14:46:14,018 thru 2017-09-07 18:56:16,318.
- **Inside this main time period 30 minute segments should be defined and the number of male employess for each department-building_type pair should be calculated for every 30 minute segment.**
- The output should include a column `start_time` that denotes the beginning of a 30 minute segment inside which the number of male employees for each department-building pair should be calculated.
- Output should be displayed in terminal (csv format is not needed)

Example of an output:

```
start_time,department,building_type,num_of_m_employees
2017-09-07 14:46:14,018,management,b,2
2017-09-07 14:46:14,018,it,a,1
2017-09-07 15:40:16,318,marketing,c,1
2017-09-07 15:40:16,318,it,a,2
2017-09-07 17:46:14,127,marketing,c,1
2017-09-07 17:46:14,127,management,a,1
2017-09-07 18:33:14,127,marketing,b,1
2017-09-07 18:33:14,127,marketing,a,1
```

I have written a program that counts the number of male employees for each department-building pair in general, but I can't do the same for each 30 minute segment. How am I to edit it?:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('test.csv') as f:
    cnt = Counter()
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[3] == "m":
            cnt[row[2], row[3]] += 1

print(cnt)
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort in question detail and formatting, but next time please show your attempt at 30 minute segments as well

Comment: I'd also recommend reading the documentation on how to properly use Counter.

Answer (score 0):

This will hopefully get you started:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

with open('test.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    start_time = None
    thirty_mins = timedelta(minutes=30)
    cnt = Counter()

    for row in csv_input:
        # Convert the first entry into a datetime object 
        dt = datetime.strptime("{} {:06}".format(row[0], int(row[1]) * 1000), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %f')

        if start_time == None:
            start_time = dt

        if dt >= start_time + thirty_mins:
            for (dept, type), count in cnt.items():
                print('{} {:03},{},{},{}'.format(start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), start_time.microsecond//1000, dept, type, count))
            start_time += thirty_mins
            cnt = Counter()

        if row[4] == "m":
            cnt[row[2], row[3]] += 1

for (dept, type), count in cnt.items():
    print('{} {:03},{},{},{}'.format(start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), start_time.microsecond//1000, dept, type, count))
```

The idea is to convert the times into a `datetime` object. With that you can determine if a row falls within the next 30 minutes boundary. Your second column appears to contain milliseconds. The datetime format uses microseconds so this needs to be converted and added.

Read each row and convert the time. Next determine if we have gone passed a 30 minute boundary. If so display the counter values for that boundary and reset the counter. Advance the time boundary by 30 minutes. Otherwise if the row is male, add to the counter.

At the end, print any remaining entries for the last boundary.

For the example you have given, this would give you:

```
2017-09-07 14:46:14 018,management,b,1
2017-09-07 14:46:14 018,it,a,1
2017-09-07 15:16:14 018,marketing,c,1
2017-09-07 15:46:14 018,it,a,2
2017-09-07 16:16:14 018,marketing,c,1
2017-09-07 16:46:14 018,management,c,1
2017-09-07 17:46:14 018,management,a,1
2017-09-07 18:16:14 018,marketing,b,1
2017-09-07 18:46:14 018,marketing,a,1
```

Note, some boundaries contain no entries.